# Subtraction of char* in implementation of strlen()

Tags: c, char, libraries, subtraction, strlen

I was looking at the implementation of strlen() function in C. I need to understand its working for one of my assignments.

```
#define ALIGN (sizeof(size_t))
#define ONES ((size_t)-1/UCHAR_MAX)
#define HIGHS (ONES * (UCHAR_MAX/2+1))
#define HASZERO(x) ((x)-ONES & ~(x) & HIGHS)

size_t strlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *a = s;
    const size_t *w;
    for (; (uintptr_t)s % ALIGN; s++) if (!*s) return s-a;
    for (w = (const void *)s; !HASZERO(*w); w++);
    for (s = (const void *)w; *s; s++);
    return s-a;
}
```

I do not understand what the subtraction of char* does here in the "return s-a" statements.

This is musl's strlen implementation. The glibc's implementation of strlen() also uses this char* subtraction.

Comment: `!*s` marks the end of the string (char is byte zero). `s-a` returns the end address (last non-nul char position + 1, where `s` currently is) minus the beginning address (`a` is a copy of the initial `s` provided to the function), thus the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation of the code annotated with comments:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *a = s;      // store a copy pointing at the start of the original        
    const size_t *w;
    for (; (uintptr_t)s % ALIGN; s++) // in case of misalignment, look for first aligned address
      if (!*s) return s-a; // if we encounter \0 while doing so, return the string length
    for (w = (const void *)s; !HASZERO(*w); w++); // work with word-sized chunks and do lookup
    for (s = (const void *)w; *s; s++); // find the exact location of \0 in the final word
    return s-a; // end minus beginning = length
}
```

Notes regarding C language compatibility:

- `w = (const void *)s` is relying on non-standard extensions and `*w` is invoking undefind behavior. This is library code so it may sometimes get compiled with specific settings such as `-fno-strict-aliasing`.
- `s-a` is actually of type `ptrdiff_t`, not `size_t`. So a cast might be required to silence compiler warnings.
- `size_t` is not necessarily the largest aligned type for the implementation, it could be larger than that. I believe the most correct type to use for 32 bit and above would be `uint_fast32_t`. The compiler/lib should make this type 32 or 64 bits depending on what's actually fastest on the 32/64 bit CPU.
- Library implementations like this one sometimes read word-sized chunks beyond the end of the passed string. This assuming that in case the string doesn't end on an aligned address, then harmless padding bytes will be present and accessible there. This is by no means guaranteed by the C standard (doing so is array out of bounds access UB), but perhaps by the local implementation.

It should be possible to uncrappify this code into something more readable & self-documenting, without affecting performance. And we can fix some of the above issues while we are at it. Perhaps something along the lines of (not tested/benchmarked):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ONES ((uint_fast32_t)-1/UCHAR_MAX)
#define HIGHS (ONES * (UCHAR_MAX/2+1))
#define HASZERO(x) ((x)-ONES & ~(x) & HIGHS)

size_t strlen (const char* s)
{
  const char* begin = s;
  const char* end   = s;

  for (; (uintptr_t)end % _Alignof(uint_fast32_t); end++)
  {
    if (*end == '\0') 
    {
      return (size_t)(end - begin);
    }
  }
  
  const uint_fast32_t* word;
  for (word = (const void*)end; !HASZERO(*word); word++)
  {}
  
  for (end = (const void*)word; end != '\0'; end++)
  {}
  
  return (size_t)(end - begin);
}
```

Comment: Another serious issue is that word search loop will read out of array bounds if array doesn't end at word boundary.

Comment: @user694733 Yep. Library implementations typically expect harmless padding bytes to be present after the end of the string. Which isn't at all guaranteed by the language standard. I can add a note about that too.

Comment: The for loop which finds the exact value of '\0' initializes the value of end = (const void*) word. Should we not use const char* instead of const void*. Can you explain why using void* works in this case?

Comment: @ShubhamSondhi The cast is there to go to/from a 32 bit pointer type to an 8 bit pointer type. They aren't compatible types, so the cast is needed. And normally quite fishy too, but this is library code. Sure you could have casted to `(const char*)` as well, it makes no difference since `void*` are compatible with all pointer types.

Comment: @ShubhamSondhi I would imagine that the original author thought it look fancy to have two rows `for (w = (const void *)s;...` and `for (s = (const void *)w; ...` written in similar ways. There isn't much in the way of a rationale explaining why the original code was written the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the string `"Hello world"`. This string is stored as an array inside the memory of your computer, and terminated by a special "null" character (`'\0'`).

The array will look something like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' | ' ' | 'w' | 'o' | 'l' | 'd' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

When this function is called (as in `strlen("Hello world")`) then `s` will be pointing to the first character in the array. The initialization of `a` will also make it point to the first character of the array.

The three loops modifies `s` so it will point to the terminating null-character.

If we again show the array, but now with the pointers, it will be something like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' | ' ' | 'w' | 'o' | 'l' | 'd' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
^                                                           ^
|                                                           |
a                                                           s
```

What `s - a` is doing is calculating the difference (in *array elements*) of the two pointers `s` and `a`. This difference will be `10` which is the length of the string (null-terminator not counted).